# Qt Creator debugger just show local variables

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt4, qt6

I am using QtCreator5.14.0 MinGW-64bit and I wrote this code :
(do not check the code, it is correct , my problem is another thing)

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    #define MAX 100
    int Solutions[MAX]={0,1};
    int CountOfCalls = 0;
    long int f(int a){
        if(a==0)
            return 0;
        if(Solutions[a])
            return Solutions[a];
        CountOfCalls++;
        return (Solutions[a] = f(a-1) + f(a-2));
    }
    int main(){
        cout<<f(40)<<endl;
        cout<<"Count of calls : "<<CountOfCalls<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

when I begin debugging at the first code in the main , right pane doesn't show global variables(here is `Solutions` array and `CountOfCalls` variable) just shows local variables.

debugging : https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dsYQ.png
my debugger settings : 
General : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJHlG.png
GDB : https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuALb.png
GDB Extended : https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVnX2.png
Locals & Expressions : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeEoD.png

I can right click and choose `add new expression evaluator` to have the `Solutions` array and `CountOfCalls` variable in the right pane , but it is boring for big source codes to add everything you want .

how to tell debugger to evaluate all global and local variables automatically?

Comment: It sometimes happens that variables are not correctly displayed in QtCreator debugger (I am using MSVC toolchain). I usually fix this by clean rebuild of the whole project. It usually helps.